# PHP header() redirect in Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, http-status-code-301

I try to make a header redirect on an Google App engine instance with

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://".$location);
header("Connection: close");
die();
```

It's working on my local development environment. On Google App Engine I receive the 301 but it doesn't redirect to the new location, instead there's a white screen.

Comment: I would suspect this has nothing to do with CakePHP. Try creating a plain old php file and put your snippet in there. Then check if that works on the Google App Engine. If not, the problem has nothing to do with CakePHP.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with CakePHP.

Comment: I edited your question to remove CakePHP. This should make the problem more clear.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Do you have a valid value for `$location` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a encoding problem. I had to urlencode() all parts of $location. On my local MAMP environment there was no problem.