# Google App Engine GAE - PHP header('Location: xxx.php') - Error: Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, header, app.yaml, google-app-engine-php

Error: Not Found

The requested URL /xxxxxx.php was not found on this server.

I am using the header('Location: xxx.php') to redirect after user authentication. I have tried looking through the Google App Engine Documents but cannot seem to find approved ways of using the header redirect. The file exist and should be incorporated in my deployment. Other than it residing on GAE I cannot find a reason why the file would not be found.

php code

```
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
```

I loosely understand what is happening with the app.yaml handlers. This is what my file looks like:

```
application: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /profile
  script: profile.php
```

Other than this (until the next bug pops up) the entire site works. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

One close answer/example I have found though:[PHP header() redirect in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227855/php-header-redirect-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 1):

creating a url handler for each page in the site helped with this. Adding the file type to the handler also helped.

```
handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /profile.php
  script: profile.php
```

It is now working!